# ipmi_ctx_open_outofband_2_0: internal error

Tags: linux, zabbix, ipmi, ilo

I want to setting monitoring ILOM in Zabbix 3.4

OS

```
Linux zabbixapp01 4.1.12-103.3.8.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Mon Aug 21 17:27:54 PDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I installed freeipmi-1.5.7 and tried test connection

```
/usr/sbin/ipmi-sensors -D LAN2_0 -h 192.168.0.21 -u username -p password -l USER -W discretereading --no-header-output --quiet-cache --sdr-cache-recreate --comma-separated-output --entity-sensor-names
```

returned error

```
ipmi_ctx_open_outofband_2_0: internal error
```

How solve this problem?

Comment: FreeIPMI maintainer here.  The "internal error" is extremely odd, indicating your motherboard has some IPMI protocol corner case that FreeIPMI does not know how to handle.  If you could, start a thread on the freeipmi mailing list with --debug output and we can try and solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryied to install other application

```
yum install OpenIPMI OpenIPMI-tools
```

checked

```
ipmitool sensor -H 192.168.0.51 -I lanplus -U username -P password -L ADMINISTRATOR
```

returned list of sensors

enabled parameter StartIPMIPollers=3

```
nano /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
```

Created own template fro example HP ILO

set data element group for example: Temperature, Voltage

after element data

```
    •   Name - PS0/P_IN
    •   Type - IPMI агент
    •   Key - PS0_P_IN
    •   IPMI sensor - PS0/P_IN 
...
```

[else view this information](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/ru/manual/config/items/itemtypes/ipmi)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with an Intel Server. Found it could work with freeipmi if you used `--cipher-suite-id=17`

Otherwise just kept saying with freeipmi (ipmi-sensors):

> ipmi_ctx_open_outofband_2_0: BMC busy

And with ipmitool:

> Error in open session response message : insufficient resources for
> session
>
> Error: Unable to establish IPMI v2 / RMCP+ session

Thought someone may find useful.  I just spent the last hour or so in it

Comment: -C17 with ipmitool I forgot to mention